# Are the audio effects of the Blender movies available to creat dubs in diferent languages?

Tags: audio

I would like to dub a few of the Blender movies, I was mainly thinking about Agent 327, but the other movies could be interesting too.

Are the different audio lines from the movie available in the Blender Cloud? I couldn't find anything about it on the website.